# Date in SQL Server different with output in .cfm

Tags: sql, sql-server, railo, application.cfm

I have SQL code like this:

```
select Date from AAA where ID = 1
```

`Date` value for `ID = 1` is `'2015-03-16'`

When I execute in SQL Server it shows `'2015-03-16'`.
But why if I execute the same query in `.cfm` it shows `'2015-03-14'` ?

All of data will have different 2 days between SQL Server and `.cfm` ?

Comment: .cfm is probably based on the same 0-date as Excel (1899-12-30 instead of 1900-01-01). Are you sure your data type is correct? Are you sure .cfm knows what the data type should be? Seems like at least one translation to integer is happening.

Comment: How are you outputting it to the cfm page? Please post the actual code you're using.

Comment: i solve the problem. i change data type from Date to Date time. Thanks :D